# How to give Null value condition in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want this condition should not work when (Me.txt_rest_value_assessment.Tex) = NULL. Because in that case, it is giving an error " Conversion from double to string error"

`If (Me.txt_rest_value_assessment.Tex) = NULL` , then it should bypass this condition

```
If CDbl(Me.txt_rest_value_assessment.Text) > _
   (CDbl(Me.txt_business_revenue_risk.Text) + CDbl(Me.txt_project_upside_value.Text)) Then

    Me.pnl_edit.Visible = True
    Me.lbl_conf_message.Text = "Rest Value Assessment value cannot be greater than Sum of Project Outlook Value and Project Upside Value."

End If
```

Comment: have you tried using `.ToString()` Method after your closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 3):

I can see at least three problems

- A TextBox.Text is never null
- In VB.NET you use Nothing
- The CDbl function is a leftover of VB6 compatibility and should be
  phased out

.

```
If string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Me.txt_rest_value_assessment.Text) Then
    ' give a message to your user about a missing required value 
    ' and return
else
    Dim assessment as Double
    Dim revenue as Double
    Dim upside as Double
    if Not double.TryParse(Me.txt_rest_value_assessment.Text, assessment) Then
         ' give a message for an invalid value to your user
         ' and return
    Else if Not double.TryParse(Me.txt_business_revenue_risk.Text, revenue) Then
         ' give a message for an invalid value to your user
         ' and return
    Else if Not double.TryParse(Me.txt_project_upside_value.Text, upside) Then
         ' give a message for an invalid value to your user
         ' and return
    End if
    If (assessment.Text > (revenue + upside)) Then
       ' let's go....

        Me.pnl_edit.Visible = True
        Me.lbl_conf_message.Text = "Rest Value Assessment value cannot be greater than Sum of Project Outlook Value and Project Upside Value."

    End If
End If
```